# Wordpress backend freezes upon edit for couple minutes

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with my Wordpress site's backend editor. I use a theme equipped with Visual Editor and whenever I start to edit a site, the backend freezes for couple minutes. After that it unfreezes and I can work freely - until updating the site and then again.
I have only this one plugin enabled, tried reinstalling Wordpress, fixing my db, reinstalling theme, changing memory limit. Nothing. Suggestions?

Comment: This sounds more client related than server and likely related to java/javascript hanging. If you use Chrome, try Firefox or vice versa and make sure your Java is up to date on your system.

Comment: @DuaneLortie Although I agree that this looks like a client-side issue, I'm a bit confused - What WordPress has to do with Java?

Comment: DOH! yup, I just had a brain cramp. Javascript is handled by the browser, so make sure that your browser(s) is/are up to date.